# Elastic Search has_child with simple_query_string

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to run the following query on our Elastic Search server.

```
{
    "query": {
        "has_child":{
            "type": "log",
            "query": {
                "simple_query_string" : {
                    "query" : "ipsum"
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The idea is to query child elements using query string, as we want to provide a flexible search to our customers.

I've tried to run this query and I get 0 results, but if I run the same query on the "log" I get a lot of results.

Anyone knows if is allowed to use query string on has_child?

-- **Edit** --

Here you have the mappings:

```
{
    "template": "*",
    "mappings": {
        "device": {
            "properties": {
                "app": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "created_at": {
                    "type": "date"
                },
                "enabled": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                },
                "id": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "name": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "type": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                },
                "udid": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                }
            }
        },
        "log": {
            "_parent": {
                "type": "device"
            }, 
            "properties": {
                "app": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "session": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "version.id": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                },                
                "version.version": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                },                
                "version.build": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                },

                "text": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "method": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "file": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "log_level": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "tag": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                },
                "time": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "date_time"
                },
                "absolute_time": {
                    "type": "long"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's strange, to be sure please try replace "simple_query_string" with "query_string"

Comment: I get the same result, 0 hits

Comment: please share your mappings.

Comment: I've added them to the original message

Comment: Just found the problem, I didn't know parent-child documents cannot be in different indexes.